# Why is The Grand Inquisitor from Dostoyevsky's The Brothers Karamazov considered to be such a powerful argument for atheism?

Tags: christianity, theodicy

Upon reading this chapter in the Brothers Karamazov I find myself confused as to why TGI is considered to be such a powerful argument for atheism and against theodicy. The chapter itself seems to state that Jesus set the bar much too high for man with respect to salvation, but isn't it true that humans were never intended to reach the level of holiness that Jesus attained and that salvation is a gift to those who repent? Also why is Ivan's description of the suffering of children such powerful ammunition for rejecting God? I appreciate any insight.

Comment: Well for one thing, if Jesus didn't mean for me to tear my eye out, he should not have commanded it.